# scrapy - AjaxMethod not available

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy, web-crawler, ajaxpro

I am trying to practice learning Scrapy web crawling and using a classified car site for the subject in order to check into countermeasures.  I know that the X-AjaxPro-Method exists because Chrome Developer Tools shows the headers being passed and proper response received.  But when done in Scrapy shell I get "This method is either not marked with an AjaxMethod or is not available."

Here are the shell commands used:

```
>>> from scrapy.http import FormRequest

>>> 
request=FormRequest(url='https://www.carwale.com/ajaxpro/CarwaleAjax.AjaxClassifiedBuyer,Carwale.ashx',headers={"X-AjaxPro-Method":"ProcessUsedCarPurchaseInquiry","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8","X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"},formdata={"profileId":"D1249107","buyerName":"","buyerEmail":"","buyerMobile":"9938223299","carModel":"","makeYear":"","pageUrl":"https://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-karnal/chevrolet-enjoy-d1249107/?rk","isP":"False","transToken":"","ltsrc":"","buyerSourceId":"4","comments":"","cwc":"buJNfItyQKBP8a3OahoJsOOmg","utma":"\"52149691.1076750176.1492103717.1492447801.1492447801.8\"","utmz":"\"52149691.1492103720.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)\"","originId":"3","isFromCaptcha":"","isGSDClick":"","isRecommended":"","isCertificationDownload":""})

>>> fetch(request)
2017-04-18 08:45:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.carwale.com/ajaxpro/CarwaleAjax.AjaxClassifiedBuyerCarwale,Carwale.ashx> (referer: None)

>>> print(response.body)
{"error":{"Message":"This method is either not marked with an AjaxMethod or is not available.","Type":"System.NotSupportedException"}}

>>>
```

The original page is at https://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-karnal/chevrolet-enjoy-d1249107/?rk=69&isP=false and a mobile phone number has to be entered in order to get "Seller Details."

So, I have dug a little further and will share some more information.  I have been able to export the XHR as a curl command using the developer tools in the browser and then trimmed this down so that it appears to me that the only required header is the X-AjaxPro-Method because the curl command works with just that header and the data.

Also got it to work using the Python requests library.

Comment: It seems your request does not identify itself as the page is expecting. You might want to copy the curl request from Chrome (inspect - network) and recreate this in Scrapy. If you put the original link + actions how to fire the ajax script, we can try to help you out as well.

Comment: I have added the original page and action as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your posted request data with what I see in Firebug, I suspect at least one of these is missing in your request:

- Cookie data (should be handled by scrapy if you turned on cookies in settings.py and made scrapy visiting https://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-karnal/chevrolet-enjoy-d1249107/?rk=69&isP=false first )
- User Agent header (set USER_AGENT in settings.py to something that looks like a real browser e.g. 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0' )
- Referer header (should be handled automatically by scrapy if you visited https://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-karnal/chevrolet-enjoy-d1249107/?rk=69&isP=false before sending the request )

All in all such ajax powered sites as carwale.com have a lot of moving parts and are a not so good object to "start learning scrapy"

PS: a better way to use FormRequest is to do `request = FormRequest.from_response(response_with_form_page, ...)`. This works well on most forms as scrapy will extract all the hidden POST parameters automatically from the form page. For details see: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response

Comment: I was able to get this to work using a scrapy Request rather than a FormRequest.  Thanks for the good advice.